# linux non-blocking socket, do I do select before send or after send?

Tags: linux, sockets, select, send

I have a non-blocking connected socket on Linux, and before my first send(), I do a select to see if the socket is ready for writing, but the select times out.

If I do not do the select, the send works fine.

If I do the select first, I never get to send anything.

Why is the select timing out before the send when the socket is obviously writable?

This is some of the code I am using:

> ```
>   fd_set writefds;
>   struct timeval timeout;//
>   FD_ZERO(&writefds);
>   FD_SET(s, &writefds);//s is my connected socket
> ```

```
  timeout.tv_sec = 10;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;

  ret = select(1, 0, &writefds, 0, &timeout);
  switch(ret)
  {
  case 1://socket is ready for writing
     bytesSent = send(s, (const char*)(buf+bytesSent), len-bytesSent, 0);
     if(SOCKET_ERROR == bytesSent)
     {
        *error = errno;
        if(EWOULDBLOCK == *error)
        {
           goto Exit;
        }
        sprintf(errmsg, ("send() failed %i\n"), *error);
     }
     else if(bytesSent < len)
     {
        sprintf(errmsg, ("send() incomplete\n"));
     }
     else
     {
        //sprintf(errmsg, ("sent %i bytes\n"), bytesSent);
     }
     break;
  case 0://timeout --!!!! always comes here
     bytesSent = -1;//treat as error
     break;
  default:
     bytesSent = -1;
  }
```

}

> Blockquote

Comment: The first parameter to your `select()` call should be `s + 1`, not 1.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I missed this in the man page. I was wondering how come it worked on Windows. I was porting Windows socket code to Linux.

Comment: Aah, on Windows, it ignores the first parameter of select()!

Comment: Glad that worked.  I promoted my comment to an answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your port from [Windows `select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to [UNIX/Berkeley-derived `select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html), you preserved the dummy value you'd supplied as the first argument to `select()`.

On UNIX, of course, this parameter (*nfds*) is meaningful and must be one greater than the highest fd in your sets.  Thus, for you it should be `s + 1`.